# Android: Supported Camera Preview Size Is Wrong Aspect Ratio

Tags: android, android-camera, surfaceview

**Solution: I was not actually setting the camera preview but rather scaling the default preview it came with. You need to assign the parameters back to the camera, because** `_camera.getParamters.setPreviewSize()` **does not work!**

I am working on getting Android cameras to preview on my phone (ideally fullscreen).

However I've run into a situation where I feel both the hardware and software are conspiring against me :/

I get a list of camera supported screen sizes. For *half* the phones (about 6 of my 12 devices) this works fine when I set the preview match the closest preview for the screen.

However on the other half, the preview is stretched and skewed. There are a number of posts that exist and claim to address this issue but do not.

The reason I am finding is this: the list of supported camera screen sizes that I am getting from the hardware itself is wrong. Why? Because when manually set the camera up to one of its highest supported sizes the aspect ratio is still off:

```
_camera.getParameters().setPreviewSize(720,1280);
getHolder().setFixedSize(720, 1280);
```

For this phone, the screen size is 768 x 1280. The closest supported screen size is 720 x 1280. Setting it to this value still results in a distorted image. The next supported screen size resolution is 1280 x 960. Which to me, is interesting, because its saying its supporting 2 different aspect ratios, but some of these 'supported' aspect ratios are skewed. i.e. it says its supports 4:3 and 16:9, but only the 4:3 comes out looking normal!

```
getHolder().setFixedSize(720, 960); //fixes issue even though this is NOT a supported screen size
```

When I force the surface holder to match a 4:3 aspect ratio, by using the non supported screen size, 720 x 960, voila, the camera preview comes out normal.

My question is, how am I supposed to know what the aspect ratio is for the camera in a camera with supported aspect ratios different than what it says?

*Update*

Digging into my phone specifics:

http://www.gsmarena.com/lg_nexus_4_e960-5048.php

This phone has a camera which saves images as 3264 x 2448. A 4:3 aspect ratio. I am going to see if I can fetch this data from the phone and use THAT for setting the desired aspect ratio.

*Update 2*

Using

```
System.out.println("Camera picture size is " + _camera.getParameters().getPictureSize().width + " x " + _camera.getParameters().getPictureSize().height);
```

It gives me 640 x 480. Which with a little maths is a 4:3 aspect ratio. I then use this and scale my camera appropriately.

It's hacky, but it gets the job done!

```
//Because the camera LIES about supporting both 16:9 and 4:3 we must find the actual one from the picture size
void determineCameraAspectRatio()
{
    int cameraWidth = _camera.getParameters().getPictureSize().width;
    int cameraHeight = _camera.getParameters().getPictureSize().height;

    if( cameraWidth*3 == cameraHeight*4)
    {
        System.out.println("4:3");
    }

    if( cameraWidth*9 == cameraHeight*16)
    {
        System.out.println("16:9");
    }
}
```

And apply the fix to the camera:

```
   if(_is4By3AspectRatio)
            {
                 height  = (Helper.screenWidthPX(_context) * 4)/3;
             }else//16:9
             {
                height = (Helper.screenWidthPX(_context) * 16)/9;
              }
                _camera.getParameters().setPreviewSize(Helper.screenWidthPX(_context),height);
                getHolder().setFixedSize(Helper.screenWidthPX(_context),height);
    }
```

*Update*

This works for a lot of phones but on some even THIS is wrong. The Nexus 6 reports a back facing camera aspect ratio of 4:3 and its highest supported ratio is 1440 x 1920 but setting it to this results in a skewed image. I have absolutely no idea why. None of this makes sense. It says it wants a 4:3 aspect ratio for the picture, but only display properly with a 16:9 ratio (front and back). SO WEIRD

Here is the sysdump on the surfaceFlinger

```
SurfaceFlinger
Build configuration: [sf] [libui] [libgui]
Sync configuration: [using: EGL_ANDROID_native_fence_sync EGL_KHR_wait_sync]
DispSync configuration: app phase 0 ns, sf phase 0 ns, present offset 0 ns (refresh 16666667 ns)
Visible layers (count = 10)
+ LayerDim 0xb8919c28 (DimLayer)
  Region transparentRegion (this=0xb8919d88, count=1)
    [  0,   0,   0,   0]
  Region visibleRegion (this=0xb8919c30, count=1)
    [  0,   0,   0,   0]
      layerStack=   0, z=        0, pos=(0,0), size=(  16,  16), crop=(   0,   0,  -1,  -1), isOpaque=0, invalidate=0, alpha=0xff, flags=0x00000001, tr=[1.00, 0.00][0.00, 1.00]
      client=0xb88ebac8
      format= 0, activeBuffer=[   0x   0:   0,  0], queued-frames=0, mRefreshPending=0
            mTexName=4 mCurrentTexture=-1
            mCurrentCrop=[49152,0,415,-1] mCurrentTransform=0
            mAbandoned=0
            -BufferQueue mMaxAcquiredBufferCount=1, mDequeueBufferCannotBlock=0, default-size=[1x1], default-format=1, transform-hint=00, FIFO(0)={}
+ LayerDim 0xb88659d0 (DimLayer)
  Region transparentRegion (this=0xb8865b30, count=1)
    [  0,   0,   0,   0]
  Region visibleRegion (this=0xb88659d8, count=1)
    [  0,   0,   0,   0]
      layerStack=   0, z=        0, pos=(0,0), size=(  16,  16), crop=(   0,   0,  -1,  -1), isOpaque=0, invalidate=0, alpha=0xff, flags=0x00000001, tr=[1.00, 0.00][0.00, 1.00]
      client=0xb88ebac8
      format= 0, activeBuffer=[   0x   0:   0,  0], queued-frames=0, mRefreshPending=0
            mTexName=5 mCurrentTexture=-1
            mCurrentCrop=[0,0,0,0] mCurrentTransform=0
            mAbandoned=0
            -BufferQueue mMaxAcquiredBufferCount=1, mDequeueBufferCannotBlock=0, default-size=[1x1], default-format=1, transform-hint=00, FIFO(0)={}
+ LayerDim 0xb886d000 (DimLayer)
  Region transparentRegion (this=0xb886d160, count=1)
    [  0,   0,   0,   0]
  Region visibleRegion (this=0xb886d008, count=1)
    [  0,   0,   0,   0]
      layerStack=   0, z=        0, pos=(0,0), size=(  16,  16), crop=(   0,   0,  -1,  -1), isOpaque=0, invalidate=0, alpha=0xff, flags=0x00000001, tr=[1.00, 0.00][0.00, 1.00]
      client=0xb88ebac8
      format= 0, activeBuffer=[   0x   0:   0,  0], queued-frames=0, mRefreshPending=0
            mTexName=6 mCurrentTexture=-1
            mCurrentCrop=[-16843010,-16843010,-16843010,-16843010] mCurrentTransform=0
            mAbandoned=0
            -BufferQueue mMaxAcquiredBufferCount=1, mDequeueBufferCannotBlock=0, default-size=[1x1], default-format=1, transform-hint=00, FIFO(0)={}
+ Layer 0xb88f9580 (com.android.phasebeam.PhaseBeamWallpaper)
  Region transparentRegion (this=0xb88f96e0, count=1)
    [  0,   0,   0,   0]
  Region visibleRegion (this=0xb88f9588, count=1)
    [  0,   0,   0,   0]
      layerStack=   0, z=    21000, pos=(0,0), size=( 768,1280), crop=(   0,   0, 768,1280), isOpaque=1, invalidate=0, alpha=0xff, flags=0x00000003, tr=[1.00, 0.00][0.00, 1.00]
      client=0xb88591d0
      format= 2, activeBuffer=[ 768x1280:1024,  3], queued-frames=0, mRefreshPending=0
            mTexName=8 mCurrentTexture=1
            mCurrentCrop=[0,0,0,0] mCurrentTransform=0
            mAbandoned=0
            -BufferQueue mMaxAcquiredBufferCount=1, mDequeueBufferCannotBlock=0, default-size=[768x1280], default-format=2, transform-hint=00, FIFO(0)={}
             [00:0xb8911cc8] state=FREE    , 0xb8868488 [ 768x1280:1024,  3]
            >[01:0xb88feb78] state=ACQUIRED, 0xb88fdc40 [ 768x1280:1024,  3]
             [02:0xb88ff1c0] state=FREE    , 0xb88fedf0 [ 768x1280:1024,  3]
+ Layer 0xb887db18 (SurfaceView)
  Region transparentRegion (this=0xb887dc78, count=1)
    [  0,   0,   0,   0]
  Region visibleRegion (this=0xb887db20, count=1)
    [  0,   0, 768, 1024]
      layerStack=   0, z=    21025, pos=(0,0), size=( 768,1024), crop=(   0,   0, 768,1024), isOpaque=1, invalidate=0, alpha=0xff, flags=0x00000002, tr=[1.00, 0.00][0.00, 1.00]
      client=0xb89124b8
      format= 4, activeBuffer=[ 640x 480: 640, 11], queued-frames=0, mRefreshPending=0
            mTexName=61 mCurrentTexture=3
            mCurrentCrop=[0,0,0,0] mCurrentTransform=0x4
            mAbandoned=0
            -BufferQueue mMaxAcquiredBufferCount=1, mDequeueBufferCannotBlock=0, default-size=[768x1024], default-format=4, transform-hint=00, FIFO(0)={}
             [00:0xb8923620] state=DEQUEUED, 0xb89000e0 [ 640x 480: 640, 11]
             [01:0xb88784c8] state=DEQUEUED, 0xb8878160 [ 640x 480: 640, 11]
             [02:0xb8878550] state=DEQUEUED, 0xb88785f0 [ 640x 480: 640, 11]
            >[03:0xb8877120] state=ACQUIRED, 0xb8878638 [ 640x 480: 640, 11]
             [04:0xb8913c48] state=DEQUEUED, 0xb886c8a0 [ 640x 480: 640, 11]
             [05:0xb88ff0f8] state=DEQUEUED, 0xb8879b08 [ 640x 480: 640, 11]
             [06:0xb8900930] state=DEQUEUED, 0xb88c3308 [ 640x 480: 640, 11]
+ Layer 0xb8862be8 (co.pumpup.app/co.pumpup.app.Activities.CameraEditorActivity)
  Region transparentRegion (this=0xb8862d48, count=1)
    [  0,   0,   0,   0]
  Region visibleRegion (this=0xb8862bf0, count=1)
    [  0,   0, 768, 1280]
      layerStack=   0, z=    21030, pos=(0,0), size=( 768,1280), crop=(   0,   0, 768,1280), isOpaque=0, invalidate=0, alpha=0xff, flags=0x00000000, tr=[1.00, 0.00][0.00, 1.00]
      client=0xb89124b8
      format= 1, activeBuffer=[ 768x1280: 768,  1], queued-frames=0, mRefreshPending=0
            mTexName=60 mCurrentTexture=2
            mCurrentCrop=[0,0,0,0] mCurrentTransform=0
            mAbandoned=0
            -BufferQueue mMaxAcquiredBufferCount=1, mDequeueBufferCannotBlock=0, default-size=[768x1280], default-format=1, transform-hint=00, FIFO(0)={}
             [00:0xb88ffff8] state=FREE    , 0xb88ed258 [ 768x1280: 768,  1]
             [01:0xb88fe908] state=FREE    , 0xb88ff3d0 [ 768x1280: 768,  1]
            >[02:0xb8872348] state=ACQUIRED, 0xb88a6110 [ 768x1280: 768,  1]
+ Layer 0xb88befc0 (FocusedStackFrame)
  Region transparentRegion (this=0xb88bf120, count=1)
    [  0,   0,   0,   0]
  Region visibleRegion (this=0xb88befc8, count=1)
    [  0,   0,   0,   0]
      layerStack=   0, z=    21031, pos=(0,0), size=(   1,   1), crop=(   0,   0,  -1,  -1), isOpaque=0, invalidate=0, alpha=0x4d, flags=0x00000001, tr=[1.00, 0.00][0.00, 1.00]
      client=0xb88ebac8
      format= 1, activeBuffer=[   0x   0:   0,  0], queued-frames=0, mRefreshPending=0
            mTexName=3 mCurrentTexture=-1
            mCurrentCrop=[524288,327680,0,0] mCurrentTransform=0
            mAbandoned=0
            -BufferQueue mMaxAcquiredBufferCount=1, mDequeueBufferCannotBlock=0, default-size=[1x1], default-format=1, transform-hint=00, FIFO(0)={}
+ LayerDim 0xb886f9c8 (DimLayer)
  Region transparentRegion (this=0xb886fb28, count=1)
    [  0,   0,   0,   0]
  Region visibleRegion (this=0xb886f9d0, count=1)
    [  0,   0,   0,   0]
      layerStack=   0, z=    22019, pos=(-192,-320), size=(1152,1920), crop=(   0,   0,  -1,  -1), isOpaque=0, invalidate=0, alpha=0x00, flags=0x00000001, tr=[1.00, 0.00][0.00, 1.00]
      client=0xb88ebac8
      format= 0, activeBuffer=[   0x   0:   0,  0], queued-frames=0, mRefreshPending=0
            mTexName=7 mCurrentTexture=-1
            mCurrentCrop=[-67372037,-67372037,1919905635,-842203036] mCurrentTransform=0
            mAbandoned=0
            -BufferQueue mMaxAcquiredBufferCount=1, mDequeueBufferCannotBlock=0, default-size=[1152x1920], default-format=1, transform-hint=00, FIFO(0)={}
+ Layer 0xb8900d20 (StatusBar)
  Region transparentRegion (this=0xb8900e80, count=1)
    [  0,   0,   0,   0]
  Region visibleRegion (this=0xb8900d28, count=1)
    [  0,   0,   0,   0]
      layerStack=   0, z=   151000, pos=(0,0), size=( 768,  50), crop=(   0,   0, 768,  50), isOpaque=0, invalidate=0, alpha=0xff, flags=0x00000001, tr=[1.00, 0.00][0.00, 1.00]
      client=0xb88fea70
      format= 1, activeBuffer=[ 768x  50: 768,  1], queued-frames=0, mRefreshPending=0
            mTexName=10 mCurrentTexture=2
            mCurrentCrop=[0,0,0,0] mCurrentTransform=0
            mAbandoned=0
            -BufferQueue mMaxAcquiredBufferCount=1, mDequeueBufferCannotBlock=0, default-size=[768x50], default-format=1, transform-hint=00, FIFO(0)={}
             [00:0xb887a088] state=FREE    , 0xb8873348 [ 768x  50: 768,  1]
             [01:0xb88fe2f8] state=FREE    , 0xb89004b8 [ 768x  50: 768,  1]
            >[02:0xb8879fd8] state=ACQUIRED, 0xb88773c8 [ 768x  50: 768,  1]
+ Layer 0xb8861748 (NavigationBar)
  Region transparentRegion (this=0xb88618a8, count=1)
    [  0,   0,   0,   0]
  Region visibleRegion (this=0xb8861750, count=1)
    [  0,   0,   0,   0]
      layerStack=   0, z=   201000, pos=(0,1184), size=( 768,  96), crop=(   0,   0, 768,  96), isOpaque=0, invalidate=0, alpha=0xff, flags=0x00000001, tr=[1.00, 0.00][0.00, 1.00]
      client=0xb88fea70
      format= 1, activeBuffer=[ 768x  96: 768,  1], queued-frames=0, mRefreshPending=0
            mTexName=11 mCurrentTexture=2
            mCurrentCrop=[0,0,0,0] mCurrentTransform=0
            mAbandoned=0
            -BufferQueue mMaxAcquiredBufferCount=1, mDequeueBufferCannotBlock=0, default-size=[768x96], default-format=1, transform-hint=00, FIFO(0)={}
             [00:0xb88fff08] state=FREE    , 0xb88fdf68 [ 768x  96: 768,  1]
             [01:0xb88c2920] state=FREE    , 0xb8862b88 [ 768x  96: 768,  1]
            >[02:0xb8913d00] state=ACQUIRED, 0xb88c5138 [ 768x  96: 768,  1]
Displays (1 entries)
+ DisplayDevice: Built-in Screen
   type=0, hwcId=0, layerStack=0, ( 768x1280), ANativeWindow=0xb885cd68, orient= 0 (type=00000000), flips=30060, isSecure=1, secureVis=0, powerMode=2, activeConfig=0, numLayers=2
   v:[0,0,768,1280], f:[0,0,768,1280], s:[0,0,768,1280],transform:[[1.000,0.000,-0.000][0.000,1.000,-0.000][0.000,0.000,1.000]]
mAbandoned=0
-BufferQueue mMaxAcquiredBufferCount=1, mDequeueBufferCannotBlock=0, default-size=[768x1280], default-format=1, transform-hint=00, FIFO(0)={}
 [00:0xb8913f80] state=DEQUEUED, 0xb88642e8 [ 768x1280: 768,  1]
>[01:0xb885fd80] state=ACQUIRED, 0xb8911608 [ 768x1280: 768,  1]
SurfaceFlinger global state:
EGL implementation : 1.4
EGL_QUALCOMM_shared_image EGL_KHR_image EGL_KHR_image_base EGL_QCOM_create_image EGL_KHR_lock_surface EGL_KHR_lock_surface2 EGL_KHR_fence_sync EGL_KHR_cl_eventEGL_KHR_cl_event2EGL_IMG_context_priority EGL_KHR_gl_texture_2D_image EGL_KHR_gl_texture_cubemap_image EGL_KHR_gl_texture_3D_image EGL_KHR_gl_renderbuffer_image EGL_EXT_create_context_robustness EGL_ANDROID_blob_cache EGL_ANDROID_framebuffer_target EGL_KHR_create_context EGL_KHR_wait_sync EGL_KHR_gl_colorspace EGL_ANDROID_image_crop EGL_ANDROID_recordable EGL_ANDROID_native_fence_sync EGL_ANDROID_image_native_buffer EGL_KHR_gl_colorspace EGL_IMG_image_plane_attribs 
GLES: Qualcomm, Adreno (TM) 320, OpenGL ES 3.0 V@95.0 AU@  (GIT@Ia6306ec328)
GL_AMD_compressed_ATC_texture GL_AMD_performance_monitor GL_AMD_program_binary_Z400 GL_EXT_debug_label GL_EXT_debug_marker GL_EXT_discard_framebuffer GL_EXT_robustness GL_EXT_texture_format_BGRA8888 GL_EXT_texture_type_2_10_10_10_REV GL_NV_fence GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture GL_OES_depth_texture GL_OES_depth24 GL_OES_EGL_image GL_OES_EGL_sync GL_OES_EGL_image_external GL_OES_element_index_uint GL_OES_fbo_render_mipmap GL_OES_fragment_precision_high GL_OES_get_program_binary GL_OES_packed_depth_stencil GL_OES_depth_texture_cube_map GL_OES_rgb8_rgba8 GL_OES_standard_derivatives GL_OES_texture_3D GL_OES_texture_float GL_OES_texture_half_float GL_OES_texture_half_float_linear GL_OES_texture_npot GL_OES_vertex_half_float GL_OES_vertex_type_10_10_10_2 GL_OES_vertex_array_object GL_QCOM_alpha_test GL_QCOM_binning_control GL_QCOM_driver_control GL_QCOM_perfmon_global_mode GL_QCOM_extended_get GL_QCOM_extended_get2 GL_QCOM_tiled_rendering GL_QCOM_writeonly_rendering GL_EXT_sRGB GL_EXT_sRGB_write_control GL_EXT_texture_sRGB_decode GL_EXT_multisampled_render_to_texture GL_EXT_color_buffer_float GL_EXT_color_buffer_half_float GL_EXT_disjoint_timer_query 
  Region undefinedRegion (this=0xb8859fe4, count=1)
    [  0, 1024, 768, 1280]
  orientation=0, isDisplayOn=1
  last eglSwapBuffers() time: 1251.335000 us
  last transaction time     : 305.204000 us
  transaction-flags         : 00000000
  refresh-rate              : 59.999999 fps
  x-dpi                     : 319.790009
  y-dpi                     : 318.744995
  gpu_to_cpu_unsupported    : 0
  eglSwapBuffers time: 0.000000 us
  transaction time: 0.000000 us
VSYNC state: disabled
  soft-vsync: disabled
  numListeners=14,
  events-delivered: 26757
    0xb88642c0: count=-1
    0xb88680e8: count=-1
    0xb88684d0: count=-1
    0xb886c8f8: count=-1
    0xb886c9b8: count=-1
    0xb886cf10: count=-1
    0xb8874450: count=-1
    0xb88ac618: count=-1
    0xb88c1658: count=-1
    0xb88fda88: count=-1
    0xb89005d0: count=-1
    0xb8912398: count=-1
    0xb89125d8: count=-1
    0xb8913e50: count=-1
h/w composer state:
  h/w composer present and enabled
Hardware Composer state (version 01020000):
  mDebugForceFakeVSync=0
  Display[0] configurations (* current):
    * 0: 768x1280, xdpi=319.790009, ydpi=318.744995, refresh=16666667
  numHwLayers=3, flags=00000000
    type   |  handle  | hint | flag | tr | blnd |   format    |     source crop (l,t,r,b)      |          frame         | name 
-----------+----------+------+------+----+------+-------------+--------------------------------+------------------------+------
       HWC | b8878638 | 0002 | 0000 | 04 | 0100 | ? 00000011  |      0,      0,    640,    480 |    0,    0,  768, 1024 | SurfaceView
       HWC | b88a6110 | 0002 | 0000 | 00 | 0105 | RGBA_8888   |      0,      0,    768,   1280 |    0,    0,  768, 1280 | co.pumpup.app/co.pumpup.app.Activities.CameraEditorActivity
 FB TARGET | b8911608 | 0000 | 0000 | 00 | 0105 | RGBA_8888   |      0,      0,    768,   1280 |    0,    0,  768, 1280 | HWC_FRAMEBUFFER_TARGET
Qualcomm HWC state:
  MDPVersion=440
  DisplayPanel=8
HWC Map for Dpy: "PRIMARY" 
PREV_FRAME: layerCount: 2    mdpCount: 2                 cacheCount: 0 
CURR_FRAME: layerCount: 2    mdpCount: 2                 fbCount: 0 
needsFBRedraw: NO  pipesUsed: 2  MaxPipesPerMixer: 4 
 ---------------------------------------------  
 listIdx | cached? | mdpIndex | comptype  |  Z  
 ---------------------------------------------  
       0 |      NO |        0 |       MDP |  0 
       1 |      NO |        1 |       MDP |  1 


Overlay State
==========================
Ctrl(mdp_overlay) id=1 z=1 fg=0 alpha=255 mask=-1 flags=0x60000
    src(msmfb_img) w=768 h=1280 format=12 MDP_RGBA_8888
    src_rect(mdp_rect) x=0 y=0 w=768 h=1280
    dst_rect(mdp_rect) x=0 y=0 w=768 h=1280
Data(msmfb_overlay_data) id=1
    data(msmfb_data) offset=0 memid=90 id=0 flags=0x0 priv=0
Attached to dpy=0

Ctrl(mdp_overlay) id=3 z=0 fg=0 alpha=255 mask=-1 flags=0x940000
    src(msmfb_img) w=480 h=640 format=6 MDP_Y_CRCB_H2V2
    src_rect(mdp_rect) x=0 y=0 w=480 h=640
    dst_rect(mdp_rect) x=0 y=0 w=768 h=1024
Data(msmfb_overlay_data) id=3
    data(msmfb_data) offset=462848 memid=123 id=0 flags=0x0 priv=0
Attached to dpy=0

Pipes used=2

MdpRotCtrl(msm_rotator_img_info) sessid=3966423424 rot=4, enable=1 downscale=0
    src w=640 h=480 format=6 MDP_Y_CRCB_H2V2
    dst w=480 h=640 format=6 MDP_Y_CRCB_H2V2
    src_rect x=0 y=0 w=640 h=480
MdpRotData(msm_rotator_data_info) sessid=3966423424 verkey=0
    src offset=0 memid=98 id=0 flags=0x0 priv=0
    dst offset=462848 memid=123 id=0 flags=0x0 priv=0
    src_chroma offset=0 memid=0 id=0 flags=0x0 priv=0
    dst_chroma offset=0 memid=0 id=0 flags=0x0 priv=0

================
Allocated buffers:
0xb8862b88:  288.00 KiB |  768 ( 768) x   96 |        1 | 0x00000900
0xb88642e8: 3840.00 KiB |  768 ( 768) x 1280 |        1 | 0x00001a00
0xb8868488: 3840.00 KiB |  768 (1024) x 1280 |        3 | 0x00000900
0xb886c8a0: unknown     |  640 ( 640) x  480 |       11 | 0x50020900
0xb8873348:  150.00 KiB |  768 ( 768) x   50 |        1 | 0x00000900
0xb88773c8:  150.00 KiB |  768 ( 768) x   50 |        1 | 0x00000900
0xb8878160: unknown     |  640 ( 640) x  480 |       11 | 0x50020900
0xb88785f0: unknown     |  640 ( 640) x  480 |       11 | 0x50020900
0xb8878638: unknown     |  640 ( 640) x  480 |       11 | 0x50020900
0xb8879b08: unknown     |  640 ( 640) x  480 |       11 | 0x50020900
0xb88a6110: 3840.00 KiB |  768 ( 768) x 1280 |        1 | 0x00000900
0xb88c3308: unknown     |  640 ( 640) x  480 |       11 | 0x50020900
0xb88c5138:  288.00 KiB |  768 ( 768) x   96 |        1 | 0x00000900
0xb88ed258: 3840.00 KiB |  768 ( 768) x 1280 |        1 | 0x00000900
0xb88fdc40: 3840.00 KiB |  768 (1024) x 1280 |        3 | 0x00000900
0xb88fdf68:  288.00 KiB |  768 ( 768) x   96 |        1 | 0x00000900
0xb88fedf0: 3840.00 KiB |  768 (1024) x 1280 |        3 | 0x00000900
0xb88ff3d0: 3840.00 KiB |  768 ( 768) x 1280 |        1 | 0x00000900
0xb89000e0: unknown     |  640 ( 640) x  480 |       11 | 0x50020900
0xb89004b8:  150.00 KiB |  768 ( 768) x   50 |        1 | 0x00000900
0xb8911608: 3840.00 KiB |  768 ( 768) x 1280 |        1 | 0x00001a00
Total allocated (estimate): 32034.00 KB
```

//Camera logic

```
private void adjustAspectRatio()
    {
        List<Camera.Size> sizesOfPreviews = _camera.getParameters().getSupportedPreviewSizes();
        Camera.Size size = getOptimalPreviewSize(sizesOfPreviews,Helper.screenWidthPX(_context),Helper.screenHeightPX(_context));

        int cameraWidth = size.height;
        int cameraHeight = size.width;

        System.out.println("Optimal camera size is " + cameraWidth + " x " + cameraHeight);
        _camera.getParameters().setPreviewSize(cameraWidth, cameraHeight);
        _parentLayout.getLayoutParams().width = 768;
        _parentLayout.getLayoutParams().height = 1024;
        //_parentLayout.setAspectRatio((double)cameraWidth/cameraHeight);
    }

    private Camera.Size getOptimalPreviewSize(List<Camera.Size> sizes, int w, int h)
    {
        final double ASPECT_TOLERANCE = 0.1;
        double targetRatio = (double) h / w;

        if (sizes == null)
            return null;

        Camera.Size optimalSize = null;
        double minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;

        int targetHeight = h;

        for (Camera.Size size : sizes) {
            double ratio = (double) size.height / size.width;
            if (Math.abs(ratio - targetRatio) > ASPECT_TOLERANCE)
                continue;

            if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
                optimalSize = size;
                minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
            }
        }

        if (optimalSize == null) {
            minDiff = Double.MAX_VALUE;
            for (Camera.Size size : sizes) {
                if (Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight) < minDiff) {
                    optimalSize = size;
                    minDiff = Math.abs(size.height - targetHeight);
                }
            }
        }

        return optimalSize;
    }
```

Comment: Using `setFixedSize()` doesn't make sense here. That sets the size of the surface itself, not the size of the view, but for a Camera preview the size of the surface is determined by the frames coming from the camera. Use `adb shell dumpsys SurfaceFlinger` to compare the size of the Surface with the size of the SurfaceView window when it's being displayed (see https://source.android.com/devices/graphics/architecture.html#composition for more info about the HWC summary in the dump). See Grafika's AspectFrameLayout or TextureView-based video player for aspect ratio correction.

Comment: Hmm but this works on 95% of the phones. But on the Nexus 6 it does not work for the back facing camera so there is a flaw in my logic. The max supported preview size for the nexus 6 is 1920 x 1440 but setting the surface to these values results in a skewed image. I've been looking at the Grafika stuff a lot but I thought I could save myself the trouble by setting the surfaceHolder size rather than the frameLayout size.

Comment: There are two sizes, the "surface" size and the "view" size. `setFixedSize()` sets the surface size, which is very useful if you're drawing the OpenGL ES or Canvas, because it sets the size of the buffer that you draw into. Frames from the camera or decoded video are passed along without copy or modification, not scale-copied into a buffer, so setting the size has no effect. They're scaled to the "view" size when displayed. Easiest way to play with it is probably TextureView; see https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/master/src/com/android/grafika/PlayMovieActivity.java#L211

Comment: You've given me a major hand up on a problem I've been stuck on for days. I'm going to dig into this and find a solution. Thank you

Comment: So I threw everything into their AspectFrameLayout and still the odd behaviour persists. On my Nexus LG, it purports to support a camera preview size of 720 x 1280. I set this to my AspectFrameLayout (which has the surfaceView as a child) and to the cameraPreviewSize and the image is coming out skewed. Am I still implementing this wrong, or is it true that the Camera will say it supports 'width x height' when really all it does is stretch the image to get there?

Comment: Try the `adb shell dumpsys SurfaceFlinger` thing from my initial comment (read the link if you haven't used it before). Because you're using a SurfaceView, the composition and scaling is performed by SurfaceFlinger, so it knows the exact sizes of the incoming images and the view, and you'll be able to see that in the dump. Paste the output here. Do note, however, that the *picture* size and the *preview* size are not the same thing, and you can't mix and match them (`getSupportedPreviewSizes()` vs. `getSupportedPictureSizes()`).

Comment: Yes I've been reading up on that but I will give it several more passes thank you.

Comment: I've added the sysDump for the nexus LG

Comment: The SurfaceView line in the HWC summary says you're displaying a 640x480 camera image in a 768x1024 view. (I can't remember what a TR of 4 means offhand, but I'm guessing it's an appropriate 90-degree rotation.) Is that what you were expecting?

Comment: I was looking at that. The app runs in portrait only mode (I already spent eons fixing the rotation for that and images that saved without EXIF data but thats another story haha). So why is it saying 640 x 480 when it says it supports up to 1280 x 960? Shouldn't the default size be the cameraPreview size? The 'optimal' size for the camera on this phone is its 1280 x 720 resolution, and I set the cameraPreviewSize to that value. I haven't set 640 x 480 anywhere in my code, where would that be coming from?

Comment: It might be a default. Make sure the value you pass to `setPreviewSize()` comes from the list returned by `getSupportedPreviewSizes()`. The set of *preview* sizes may be much shorter than the list of *picture* sizes, and may not include some of the larger resolutions. In contrast, the value you pass to `setPictureSize()` must come from the `getSupportedPictureSizes()` list.

Comment: I posted my code and I think I've been doing just that. When the camera is ready I get a list of the sizes and set the cameraPreviewSize. Isn't setting thePictureSize for what it saves the picture as (when the camera callback fires)?

Comment: `_camera.getParameters().setPreviewSize(cameraWidth, cameraHeight)` has no effect. `getParameters()` gets a copy of the parameter block, not a reference to internal state. You must get the parameters, modify them with e.g. `setPreviewSize()`, and then call `setParameters()` to put the new values into effect.

Comment: Holy cow thats good to know. Wow Im going to take a look at this tomorrow. Thanks for pointing that out, I knew there had to be something extremely fundamentally wrong with my code

Comment: Well that seems to be the root of the WHOLE problem. I was never setting the camera preview size, I was always just scaling the default preview size and SOMETIMES I scaled it in accordance with the correct aspect ratio and sometimes I didn't (hence its sporadic success). Thank you immensely, the problem is fixed

Comment: Can you please help me on this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36349530/camera-size-and-43-aspect-ratio-is-not-matching