# mCameraParameters.setPreviewSize causes takePicture callback to not fire

Tags: android, android-camera

I am trying to set a camera parameter `setPreviewSize` with a certain size, in my case 1280 x 720, on a Samsung galaxy s3 (i9300).

```
cameraParameters.setPreviewSize(1280, 720);//1280, 720 is in the getSupportedPreviewSizes
mCamera.setParameters(cameraParameters);
```

This preview size is listed as a "supported size" under `cameraParameters.getSupportedPreviewSizes`. In this case it is the 2nd one (index 1).

When I set the preview size to this, the preview works. I get the video stream displayed, but it appears that I do no longer get the jpeg `PictureCallback` when I call `mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture)`.

If i set the preview size to `970, 720` the callbacks get fired.

Is there maybe some of the preview sizes that disables taking pictures? Or could this be hardware issues maybe?

Comment: Have you tried to use the setPictureSize method? Can you notice any difference? Also, is the onPictureTaken() callback firing any exception?

Comment: interesting. When i set the `setPictureSize` to `1280, 720` and have the same for setPreviewSize, everything works.

Comment: Since this has helped you, I'll convert it to an answer. Although, it needs further explanation

Comment: Have you try to get the supported picture sizes, getSupportedPictureSizes()? And try to set the one that you want in the setPictureSize()? Can you see any difference now?

Comment: I just did. The default picture size is `3264, 2448`, which is in the supportedPictureSizes.

Comment: AHA!! I believe it is because the preview size and picture size was in different aspect rations!

Answer (score 1):

Try to set the picture size, i.e.:

```
 setPictureSize(1280, 720);
```

Comment: This helped a lot! The actual problem was that the previewsize and picture size was in different aspect ratios (16:9 vs 4:3). Getting the aspects equal fixed the problem! Thanks!

Comment: @Cort3z Do you allow rotation? The aspect ratio will change if the device rotates

Comment: I am doing some stuff with rotation, yes, but it does not rotate after i have started it. (screen rotation is off). If you add some info about aspect ratio (and maybe even rotation), I will accept :)

Comment: @Cort3z Check that out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30714469/android-supported-camera-preview-size-is-wrong-aspect-ratio?rq=1

Comment: @Cort3z There seems to be a relation between the aspect ratio of the preview and the aspect ratio of the picture itself. So, you have find the aspect ratio of the preview, let's say 4:3. In this case you have to set the picture size that will have the same aspect ratio. Also, in this case you'll probably avoid the distortion of the image. If you'll try that, could you please update the thread? I'm really curious..